# While creating a bar graph using d3 how to associate the bar height with the numbers on the scale?

Tags: d3.js

When creating a bar graph with data for both the axis in d3.js, how do I link the position and height of the bar with the numbers on the axes?

Comment: Add the code you have written, so that people can help you.

Comment: Use a package like c3.js that generates bar charts in d3 and does that for you - http://c3js.org/examples.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no point adding new libraries as mentioned in the comments. Just scale your width and height of your bars with your axis.

Simple example : http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8952219

Notice these lines of code :

```
 svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
```

He is passing the number he wants to use as the height (d.value) to the y scale. That way the labels on the axis coincide to the height of the bars

Comment: Yes I got it. Thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: Scaling the data works only on the data which are numbers right?How to deal with the textual data. For example say months of a year.

Comment: you set the width so theyre all the same and you just pass the data you want to show on the ticks to the domain like so :x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));

Comment: its all in the example provided

Comment: Sorry my bad. Din't see properly. Thanks a lot anyways.